# Choosing an existing item from WPF Frame navigation history instead of re-adding it

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

I'm using WPF Frame to show some pages:

```
frame.Content = page;
```

this will add an item to the navigation history every time I set the frame's content.
I need to navigate existing item if exists in navigation history (Not add a new one)

I've tested BackStack and ForwardStack to find like this:

```
try{

foreach(var item in frame.BackStack){
        if(item.GetType() == typeof(MyPage)){
                frame.Content = item;
        }
}
}catch{}
```

But these codes does not work because always the BackStack is null

How can I do this?

Comment: There is no `BackStack` if you set the `Content` to the same `Page` instance. How are you navigating between pages?

Comment: @mm8 after posting this question I tried to navigate via frame.Navigate() method but it was not working too. There are several menu items which are navigating the frame.

Comment: Please include some code in your question that can be use to reproduce your issue then. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).